# If $X=S^2$ and $A$ is a finite set of $k$ points in $X$, show $\tilde{H}_0(A)\simeq\mathbb{Z}^{k-1}$ and $\tilde{H}_i(A)=0$ for $i>0$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

If we have $X=S^2$ and $A$ is a finite set of $k$ points in $X$, I would like to show that $\tilde{H}_0(A)\simeq\mathbb{Z}^{k-1}$ and $\tilde{H}_i(A)=0$ for $i>0$.

I understand the definition of relative homology but I am still new to it, I find it hard to find some clue on how to proceed.

Here is my attempt:

We have the long exact sequence: $\ldots\to\tilde{H}_0(A)\xrightarrow{i_*}\tilde{H_0}(X)\xrightarrow{j_*}\tilde{H}_0(X/A)\to0$.

I guess $H_0(A)=\mathbb{Z}^k$. But how can we relate to $\tilde{H}_0(A)$? Could somebody please give some hints and guidance on how to proceed?

I have been looking at many sources for the definition of long exact sequence, relative homology, but still find it quite hard to apply the concepts in solving problems.

Any helps are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $H_0(A) = \mathbb{Z}^k$

Comment: @PenasRaul thanks for mentioning, that was a typo.

Comment: The fact that $A$ is included in $S^2$ is a red herring. Simply show that $\tilde{H}^i$ of a singleton is zero and use the additive property of homology.

Comment: Also, the relation between $H_n$ and $\tilde{H_n}$ is the following. For $n> 0 $ they are isomorphic, and for $n=0$ you have $H_0 = \tilde{H_0} / ker k$ where $k$ sends any point to $1$ (so basically counts the number of points in your formal sum).

In this case $H_0 = \mathbb{Z}^{k-1}$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi thanks for the clue, but I am still find it hard to understand your clue, how can we show $\tilde{H}_i$ of a singleton is zero? Do you mean $\tilde{H}_i(A)$ or $\tilde{H}_i(X)$? Which additive property are you referring to? I am really clueless, sorry.

Comment: @PenasRaul I see. The map $k$ that you mentioned is a map between which spaces? Is it $k:H_0\to\tilde{H}_0$? Also why is $H_0=\mathbb{Z}^{k-1}$, did you previously say $H_0(A)=\mathbb{Z}^k$?

Comment: @user338393 It is actually a homomorphism $\epsilon\colon C_0 (X) \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $\sum_i n_i x_i \mapsto \sum_i n_i$. The singular complex followed by $\epsilon$ is the "augmented chain complex", and it calculates $\tilde{H}_\bullet (X)$. The relation you are looking for is $H_0 \cong \tilde{H}_0 \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. You have $H_0 (A) \cong \mathbb{Z}^k$ and $\tilde{H}_0 (A) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{k-1}$.